# FullCalendar V5 compatibility issue with LWC ,Its working fine with V4

Tags: lightning-web-components, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar V4 in existing project with LWC  & its working fine , however we have made some changes in core/main.min.js (in V4), the changes are made to convert it to UMD format

```
var FullCalendar = (function (exports) {
```

to

```
    **(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? 
     factory(exports) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
    (global = global || self, factory(global.FullCalendar = {}));
}(this, function (exports) {**
```

But if we  DONT Change main.js in V5  Script is getting loaded  but it is saying  **"FullCalendar is not defined"**

AND If we are making changes as we did in V4 just to make it compatible with LWC , Calendar is loading  but on click on calendar it is rendering back to Previous Month

Any Help is appreciated.

> Following is Link to get script

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/getting-started

**My JS**

```
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import calendarResource from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/fullcalendar5';
export default class Calendar extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, calendarResource + '/lib/main.js'),
            loadStyle(this, calendarResource + '/lib/main.css')
        ]).then(() => {
            try {
                var ele = this.template.querySelector('.calendar');
                var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(ele, {});
                calendar.render();
    
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error calendar init', error);
            }

        }).catch(error => {
            console.error('Error promise all', error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get v5 working with LWC?

Comment: Yes sir.. But it is having compatibility issues or may be something else.. It's rendering but it's not functional

Comment: Have you gotten any further with getting it working @SwarandeepSingh?

Comment: No we did roll back to V4.. But V4 has some bugs which were rectified in V4

Comment: I mean bugs were rectified in V5